# Is having to remove glasses to read normal?

Tags: eye

Is it typical that a myopic who wears corrective lenses would need to remove their glasses in order to read or is this an indication that the prescription is wrong.

Comment: I'm myopic (around -8) and wear glasses. The doctor tells me to always wear the glasses and read from 1 feet distance, not less than that. However for me I feel that is not okay for fine-works in nearby-distance,   like thin-sectioning and dissecting tiniest objects. Putting off the glass improve vision for them. Also sometimes putting off the glasses to read nearby-things, gives me more comfort (less-stress). So I could feel what you're exactly trying to tell.